# How to make buttons to hide and show markers?

Tags: javascript, google-maps

In Google maps, I want to have buttons that will hide and show map markers, but I need to have multiple buttons, each with their own set of markers.  For example, button 1 would show and hide markers 1 and 3, while button 2 would show and hide markers 2 and 4.

It's kinda hard for me cause I'm new in api v3.

Here is my code.

```
  function initialize() {

    var mapDiv = document.getElementById('map-canvas');
    var map = new google.maps.Map(mapDiv, {
      center: new google.maps.LatLng(-8.762472, -63.887951),
      zoom: 13,
      mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP       });


  var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
      map: map,
      position: new google.maps.LatLng(-8.759662,-63.906489),      
      icon:  predio});


   var infowindow    =  new google.maps.InfoWindow({
  content:contentimage})
 google.maps.event.addListener(marker,'click',function(){
infowindow.open(map,marker); });


var marker1 = new google.maps.Marker({
      map: map,
      position: new google.maps.LatLng(-8.766159,-63.889567),      
      icon:  yellow});


  var infowindow1    =  new google.maps.InfoWindow({
 content:contentimage1})
   google.maps.event.addListener(marker1,'click',function(){
infowindow1.open(map,marker1); });
}
```

Comment: http://www.geocodezip.com/v3_MW_example_categories.html looks like an example that might be helpful (though it's using checkboxes rather than buttons)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### You may like this

[**A Working Example Here**](http://jsfiddle.net/X5r8r/788/).

```
function init()
{
    // Icon urls for 4 icons
    var bell="http://image1.png", cam="http://image2.png",
    black="http://image3.png", green="http://image4.png";
    // Image urls for 4 images
    conimg1="http://contentImage1.jpg", conimg2="http://contentImage2.jpg",
    conimg3="http://contentImage3.jpg", conimg4="http://contentImage4.jpg",

    var map,
    locations = [
        [42.82846160000000000000, -76.53560419999997000000, bell, conimg1],
        [43.65162010000000000000, -77.73558579999997000000, black, conimg2],
        [44.75846240000000000000, -78.22252100000003000000, cam, conimg3],
        [41.71773540000000000000, -75.74897190000002000000, green, conimg4]
    ],
    myOptions = {
       zoom: 6,
       center: new google.maps.LatLng(locations[0][0], locations[0][1]),
       mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    };
    var mapDiv = document.getElementById('map');
    map = new google.maps.Map(mapDiv, myOptions);
    var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow(), marker, i, markers=[];
    for (i = 0; i < locations.length; i++) {  
        marker = new google.maps.Marker({
            position: new google.maps.LatLng(locations[i][0], locations[i][1]),
            map: map,
            icon: locations[i][2],
            visible:true   
         });
         markers.push(marker)
         google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click',(function(marker, i){
             return function() {
                 var img="<img class='contentImage' src='"+locations[i][3]+"' />";
                 infowindow.setContent(img);
                 infowindow.open(map, marker);
             }
         })(marker, i));
     }

    var btn1=document.getElementById('btn1');
    google.maps.event.addDomListener(btn1, 'click', function(){
        if(markers[0].visible)
        {   
            this.innerHTML="Show Icons (1 and 2)";
            this.className="btn"; 
            markers[0].setVisible(false);
            markers[1].setVisible(false);
        }
        else
        {
            this.innerHTML="Hide Icons (1 and 2)";
            this.className="btn btn-primary";
            markers[0].setVisible(true);
            markers[1].setVisible(true);  
        }    
    });

    var btn2=document.getElementById('btn2'); 
    google.maps.event.addDomListener(btn2, 'click', function(){
        if(markers[2].visible)
        {   
            this.innerHTML="Show Icons (3 and 4)";
            this.className="btn";
            markers[2].setVisible(false);
            markers[3].setVisible(false);
        }
        else
        {
            this.innerHTML="Hide Icons (3 and 4)";
            this.className="btn btn-primary";
            markers[2].setVisible(true);
            markers[3].setVisible(true);  
        }    
    });
}
```

Comment: hello friend, so I did as you said, but apparently has an error in creating the var map, location [] .. sorry but I can not find the error ..

the idea is wonderful .. I only have to replace the images and contens and create buttons and assign the class to the event listener .. Is that right?


thanks a lot

Comment: Yes that's right and please copy the code from the working example in fiddle and also make sure `map-canvas` is `map` because I've used `<div id="map"></div>`.

Comment: thanks man .. you help a lot but unintentionally abuse their good will and knowledge, how do I add a table to the marker infowindow to show other content .. for exemple: table 1 show info and description and table 2 show pictures ..

graciously

Comment: sorry for being a layman but could you send me the code to copy and paste html page dreamweaver .. is the last thing I ask .. : D thanks again!!

Comment: Sorry, I wasn't here, anyways, the code is in [this example](http://jsfiddle.net/X5r8r/788/) and you can insrt table here, like `var img="<img class='contentImage' src='"+locations[i][3]+"' />";img+="<table>...</table>"`.

Comment: [Another example with table added](http://jsfiddle.net/X5r8r/793/) and copy everything from this example, including html and css.

Comment: hello again my friend :D !   i got some problens trying to copy and paste the  code in dreamweaver .. can u land me a hand again? when i paste doesnt work and i have no clue man.. :(  .. maybe call <script> for jquery and CSS text type .. yeah im stuck.. i fear it was easy and i fail

Comment: I think it's working in my examples and you didn't tell me anything about the problem but anyways, glad to know that you have solved it.